# How i can fix my c# console net framework PacMan game?

Tags: c#

I started writing pacMan console game and have problems with pacMan moving, i can move him only left, if i move him up, down or right very strange things happens, but my code looks good. Please check my runGame function in RunGame class(here i have code for moving) and tell me how to fix it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PacMan
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            gameField.setGameArr();
            gameField.drawField();

            while (true)
            {
                RunGame.runGame();
            }
        }
    }

    class gameField
    {
        public static Random random = new Random();

        public static string[,] gameArr = new string[28, 84]; // 28 rows and 84 columns | Row - y coordinate, Column - x
        public static int xNum = gameArr.GetUpperBound(1); 
        public static int yNum = gameArr.GetUpperBound(0);

        public static void setGameArr()
        {
            gameArr[5, 5] = PacMan.rightSprite;

            for (int y = 0; y < yNum; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < xNum; x++)
                {
                    if (y == 0 || x == 0 || y == yNum - 1 || x == xNum - 1)
                    {
                        gameArr[y, x] = "#";
                    }
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
                {
                    if (gameArr[i, j] == null)
                        gameArr[i, j] = ".";
                }
            }
        }

        public static void drawField()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < yNum; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < xNum; x++)
                {
                    if (gameArr[y, x] != null)
                        Console.Write(gameArr[y, x]);
                    else Console.Write("");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class PacMan
    {
        public static string upSprite = "v";
        public static string downSprite = "^"; //"ᗣ";
        public static string rightSprite = "<"; //"ᗧ";
        public static string leftSprite = ">"; //"ᗤ";

        public static (int y, int x) getPlayerPos()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gameField.yNum; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < gameField.xNum; x++)
                {
                    if (gameField.gameArr[y, x] == upSprite ||
                        gameField.gameArr[y, x] == downSprite ||
                        gameField.gameArr[y, x] == rightSprite ||
                        gameField.gameArr[y, x] == leftSprite)
                    {
                        return (y, x);
                    }
                }
            }

            return (0, 0);
        }
    }

    class RunGame
    {
        public static void runGame()
        {
            (int y, int x) playerPos = PacMan.getPlayerPos();

            ConsoleKeyInfo ki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow &&
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x - 1] != "#")
            {
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x] = null;

                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x - 1] = PacMan.leftSprite;

                Console.Clear();
                gameField.drawField();
            }
            if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow &&
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x + 1] != "#")
            {
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x] = null;

                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x + 1] = PacMan.rightSprite;

                Console.Clear();
                gameField.drawField();
            }
            if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow &&
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y - 1, playerPos.x] != "#")
            {
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x] = null;

                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y - 1, playerPos.x] = PacMan.upSprite;

                Console.Clear();
                gameField.drawField();
            }
            if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow &&
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y + 1, playerPos.x] != "#")
            {
                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x] = null;

                gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y + 1, playerPos.x] = PacMan.downSprite;

                Console.Clear();
                gameField.drawField();
            }
        }
    }

    class Ghost
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x + 1]`  You aren't doing any bounds-checking on your array lookups.  What if `playerPos.x + 1` is outside the bounds of the array?

Comment: Probably just assign a space instead of null.  `gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x] = null;` --> `gameField.gameArr[playerPos.y, playerPos.x] = " ";` (in all 4 places you do so).  Or in the output function change `else Console.Write("");` to `else Console.Write(" ");`

Comment: Welcome to SO!  A good question to ask, rather than "strange things happening" is to describe *what* strange things happen.  Can you provide any screenshots, or something that would assist potential answerers in helping your problem?